# fourier: How to get slanted lower and upper case Greek symbols by default

Tags: math-mode, capitalization, greek, slanted, fourier

The fourier package has an option to slant lower case Greek; the upright lower case Greek symbols are then available as `\other<symbol>` macros. It seems upper case Greek symbols are always upright by default; the slanted symbols are again available as `\other<Symbol>`.

Is it possible to also get slanted upper case Greek symbols, i.e., using the standard `\<Symbol>` macros and get the upright variants through `\other<Symbol>` (or another variant macro set).

I know the isomath package (officially incompatible with fourier) ensures slanted upper case Greek symbols; however, the `\other<Symbol>` macros then remain slanted.

Comment: I don't know. But if you load the `isomath` package it sets the uppercase slanted, among other things, which could be a problem: `\usepackage{fourier}\usepackage{isomath}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I's say this is a long standing bug of `fourier`; with the `sloped` option, the font used for `letters` and `otherletters` are swapped with respect to those used when the option is not used; but *also* the definitions of `\Gamma` and `\otherGamma` are swapped (and similarly for the other uppercase Greek letters). So in the end the same actions are performed with or without the option, as far as uppercase Greek is concerned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sloped]{fourier}

% fourier.sty has `otherletters' here
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathord}{letters}{000}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathord}{letters}{001}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Theta}{\mathord}{letters}{002}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lambda}{\mathord}{letters}{003}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xi}{\mathord}{letters}{004}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathord}{letters}{005}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sigma}{\mathord}{letters}{006}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsilon}{\mathord}{letters}{007}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Phi}{\mathord}{letters}{008}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Psi}{\mathord}{letters}{009}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathord}{letters}{010}

% fourier.sty has `letters' here
\DeclareMathSymbol{\otherGamma}{\mathord}{otherletters}{000}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\otherDelta}{\mathord}{otherletters}{001}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\otherTheta}{\mathord}{otherletters}{002}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\otherLambda}{\mathord}{otherletters}{003}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\otherXi}{\mathord}{otherletters}{004}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\otherPi}{\mathord}{otherletters}{005}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\otherSigma}{\mathord}{otherletters}{006}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\otherUpsilon}{\mathord}{otherletters}{007}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\otherPhi}{\mathord}{otherletters}{008}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\otherPsi}{\mathord}{otherletters}{009}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\otherOmega}{\mathord}{otherletters}{010}


\begin{document}
$\alpha\beta\Gamma$

$\otheralpha\otherbeta\otherGamma$
\end{document}
```

[image]